# When does Leray spectral sequence degenerate?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two projective algebraic varieties over a field $k$ and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be smooth proper morphism.

My question is when Leray's spectral sequence for coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ degenerates.

For example, when $k$ is the field of complex numbers, is the Leray spectral sequence always degenerated? If not when does it degenerate? What about the characteristic $p$ case?

Comment: It is very rare that it degenerates.  If $f$ is affine, i.e., finite and 'etale, then the spectral sequence degenerates.  If there is a unique integer $q$ such that $R^qf_*$ of the sheaf is nonzero, then the spectral sequence degenerates; similarly if there exists an integer $n$ such that each group $H^p(X,R^qf_*(-))$ is nonzero only if $p=n$.  Apart from these cases,  most cases are related to Hodge theory (for some of these, we also have purely algebraic proofs).  You might look up the proof of Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing in Koll'ar-Mori for more details.